# Javascript - mock FormData.entries() in unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I am trying to unit test submitting of form in javascript. This is how I mock the FormData:

```
function FormDataMock() {
  this.append = jest.fn();
}
global.FormData = FormDataMock
```

But I have a problem to mock later in the function I'm testing I'm iterating over entries in form by `FormData.entries()`, the problem is that I don't know how to mock `.entries()` function. I have tried to assign the function to entries but it did not help me. I'm still getting `entries is not a function`. Do you have any idea, how to mock `.entries()` function in FormData? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the same as `.append` like `this.entries = jest.fn()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
const entries = jest.fn()
const append = jest.fn()
global.FormData = () => ({ entries, append })
```